# Why is the Riemannian exponential map only defined for unit time, and not for all time

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)), the (Riemannian) exponential map for a point $p\in M$ takes a vector $v\in T_pM$ and maps it to the point displaced 1 unit of time along the geodesic of $v$ initialized at $p$:

$$\exp_p(v) = \gamma_v(1)$$

Where $\gamma_v(t)$ is the unique geodesic such that $\gamma_v'(0)=v$ and $\gamma_v(0) = p$

My question is about why the emphasis is put on just 1 time? I can see a generalization being, for $s\in \mathbb{R}$, $\exp_p(sv) = \gamma_v(s)$ to serve as a 1-parameter map (or would it be a family of maps?) to any point along the geodesic. This seems to be possible, since we can just define a new vector $w = sv$ so that $\exp_p(w) = \gamma_w(1)$... and because they are geodesics, $\gamma_w'(0) = s\gamma_v'(0)$ means in general $\gamma_w'(t) = s\gamma_v'(t)$ so $\gamma_w(t) = \gamma_v(st)$ and therefore $\exp_p(w) = \exp_p(sv) = \gamma_v(s)$.

So why is it restricted to unit time? Thank you.

Comment: But, it's defined at each $v\in T_pM$.  So for $sv$, we already have $\rm{exp}_p(sv)=\gamma_{sv}(1)$.  So it was just a matter of choosing which $t$ to evaluate $\gamma_v$ at.  I'm not sure what would happen to various theorems in the subject if that were changed.   But $1$ was chosen.   I certainly don't recall what the implications are for the Gauss lemma etc.  Good luck getting a better answer. That the exponential map is a radial isometry is a nice result.

Comment: Correction,  it's defined at each $v$ in a small neighborhood of zero in the tangent space.   I.e. it's locally defined.   By Hopf-Rinow, it's defined on the whole tangent space if the metric is complete.   So for instance when the manifold is compact.